# Disable phone number parsing in iPhone email subject

Tags: iphone, email

Is there a way to prevent iOS / iPhone from parsing a phone number like string in an email subject when sending an email to one of these devices?

Ex. Subject: "Test Email 1234567" results in an undesired phone number link

I've tried the solutions in the following questions, but those only work for links in the body, not the subject

[How do you disable phone number linking in iPhone Mail app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478183/how-do-you-disable-phone-number-linking-in-iphone-mail-app)

[How do you dissable phone number detection in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649702/how-do-you-dissable-phone-number-detection-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 0):

You could access the view and disable data detection, unfortunately you can't do that according to the documentation:

> Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.